# VueJS - anexando um arquivo PDF para download

Tags: vue.js, pdf

Estou criando meu portfólio em vuejs, criei um link para disponibilizar o arquivo para download (pdf) mas está fazendo download do html.

home -views --home

organização da pasta (arquivo pdf) -assets --pdf

html

```
<a :href="dow" download="Curriculum">
 <span class="dow"></span>
</a>
```

JS

```
data ( ) {
    return {
          dow: '@/assets/CurriculumR.pdf',
 }
}
```

Comment: Esse link pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015954/how-to-download-a-locally-stored-file-in-vuejs

Comment: Emerson, não achei esse arquivo `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por se tratar de um projeto com vue cli 2 > é necessário criar o arquivo vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(pdf)(\?.*)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                name: 'files/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Com isso o webpack vai entender e fazer o parse desse tipo de arquivo e permitir manipular através do asset gerado.

Comment: Obrigado, já salvou minha vida aqui.